# Saving time as timestamp in database with PHP

Tags: php, datetime

From the front-end I am taking a time string by three separate input fields: `hour`, `minute` and `mode` (for am/pm). Then in the back-end I am concatenating all these three inputs to make up something like this: `12:05pm`

The DB column in which I want to store this time is in `timestamp` format. If I insert this string, mysql force converts it to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. How can I insert the time?

Comment: Add a date to the time string?

Comment: ............How?

Comment: If your storing time only then use `time` data type.

Comment: @SalmanA I used it at first. But it was giving me a hard time manipulating in the front-end. For instance `02:01pm` would be stored in mysql as `14:01:00` But I don't know how to convert `14:01:00` into a JS date object. But now, changing it to a timestamp, I can pass it in JS `Date()` constructor and show it as `02:01pm` easily.

Comment: @Eisenheim don't store the data in desired format. Store the data in native format. Format it on the front-end. What if the client tells you that he now wants to see time in military format instead of am/pm? Would you change the data all over the place? Besides, JS date parsing is not guaranteed to work as expected across all browsers.

Comment: @SalmanA _Format it on the front-end_ -- How do you format `14:01:00` to display `02:01pm` on the front-end? Like I said, I had to change the data type because I couldn't format it.

Comment: @Eisenheim it needs a 2-3 lines of PHP/JavaScript code.

Comment: Right now, I am able to pass my time into `Date()` like this: `new Date(mytime).toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })` and use `toLocaleString()` method to format it. Because `mytime` here is a **timestamp** and JS `Date()` constructor understands timestamp and converts it into a date object. When I try to pass it a **time** like `14:01:00`, I get _Invalid Date_ Can you suggest me any mechanism by which I will be able to translate `14:01:00` into `02:01pm`? Then I will be happy to change my column data type from `timestamp` to `time`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the date and and concatenate the time with date and conver it into strtotime like below

```
$timestamp = '02:01pm';
$currentDateTime = date('Y-m-d');
$newDate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($currentDateTime." ".$timestamp));
echo $newDate;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Please consider that `$yourstring` contains `02:01pm`

Comment: then you need to change your datatype from timestamp to varchar, you can not save 02:01pm in timestamp datatype

Comment: I wasn't trying to save the string, I was trying to store a timestamp which contained the time from that string. In case of `02:01pm`, it would be something like: `2018-07-10 14:01:00`

Comment: Please have a look on updated answer, if it solve your problem